# Open Web Analytics visitor emaid tracking doesn't work

Tags: javascript, java, openwebanalytics

I Integrated the open web analytics to my application and it's working fine.
my application is visited by many users. In the secondary Dimension drop down having the visitor email id.
1. How to push the user details like user name, email id in to OWA.
 I tried with setUserName() to push the username into OWA. But in dash board how to filter based on the username?. 
2. what is the method to push the email id also how to filter the result based on the email id. Thanks in advance